# CSS menu alignment

Tags: css

I am trying to align the secondary nav to the left side so it is flush with the primary nav.

I am centering the whole page by setting the body margins to auto, and using fixed width for a wrapper. This means I can't just set the position to absolute.

Current situation:
[image: current situation]

Desired situation:
[image: Desired situation]

How can I achieve this with css?

---

EDIT: Add the code

### HTML

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
  <li class="page_item page-item-23"><a title="Home" href=
  "http://x/wp/?page_id=23">Home</a></li>

  <li class="page_item page-item-24 current_page_ancestor current_page_parent">
    <a title="About Client" href="http://x/wp/?page_id=24">About Client</a>

    <ul class="children">
      <li class="page_item page-item-30"><a title="Who We Are" href=
      "http://x/wp/?page_id=30">Who We Are</a></li>

      <li class="page_item page-item-31"><a title="Mission, Vision &amp; Core Values"
      href="http://x/wp/?page_id=31">Mission, Vision &amp; Core Values</a></li>

      <li class="page_item page-item-33 current_page_item"><a title="Our Team" href=
      "http://x/wp/?page_id=33">Our Team</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="page_item page-item-25"><a title="Where We Work" href=
  "http://x/wp/?page_id=25">Where We Work</a></li>

  <li class="page_item page-item-26">
    <a title="What We Do" href="http://x/wp/?page_id=26">What We Do</a>

    <ul class="children">
      <li class="page_item page-item-48"><a title="Monitoring and Evaluation" href=
      "http://x/wp/?page_id=48">Monitoring and Evaluation</a></li>

      <li class="page_item page-item-59"><a title="Health and Nutrition" href=
      "http://x/wp/?page_id=59">Health and Nutrition</a></li>

      <li class="page_item page-item-61"><a title="Health Systems Strengthening"
      href="http://x/wp/?page_id=61">Health Systems Strengthening</a></li>

      <li class="page_item page-item-63"><a title="Food Security and Livelihoods"
      href="http://x/wp/?page_id=63">Food Security and Livelihoods</a></li>

      <li class="page_item page-item-65"><a title="Institutional Development" href=
      "http://x/wp/?page_id=65">Institutional Development</a></li>

      <li class="page_item page-item-68"><a title="Environment" href=
      "http://x/wp/?page_id=68">Environment</a></li>

      <li class="page_item page-item-71"><a title="Gender Studies" href=
      "http://x/wp/?page_id=71">Gender Studies</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="page_item page-item-27"><a title="Partnerships" href=
  "http://x/wp/?page_id=27">Partnerships</a></li>

  <li class="page_item page-item-28"><a title="Resources" href=
  "http://x/wp/?page_id=28">Resources</a></li>

  <li class="page_item page-item-29"><a title="Contact Us" href=
  "http://x/wp/?page_id=29">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS (original from sandbox template)

```
div.skip-link {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1em;
    top: 1em;
}
div#menu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
    height: 1.5em;
    margin: 1em 0;
    width: 100%;
}
div#menu ul, div#menu ul ul {
    line-height: 1;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div#menu ul a {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 1em;
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
div#menu ul ul ul a {
    font-style: italic;
}
div#menu ul li ul {
    left: -999em;
    position: absolute;
}
div#menu ul li:hover ul {
    left: auto;
}
.entry-title, .entry-meta {
    clear: both;
}
div#container, div#primary {
    margin-top: 2em;
}
form#commentform .form-label {
    margin: 1em 0 0;
}
form#commentform span.required {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    color: #CC3300;
}
form#commentform, form#commentform p {
    padding: 0;
}
input#author, input#email, input#url, textarea#comment {
    padding: 0.2em;
}
div.comments ol li {
    margin: 0 0 3.5em;
}
textarea#comment {
    height: 13em;
    margin: 0 0 0.5em;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 66%;
}
.alignright, img.alignright {
    float: right;
    margin: 1em 0 0 1em;
}
.alignleft, img.alignleft {
    float: left;
    margin: 1em 1em 0 0;
}
.aligncenter, img.aligncenter {
    display: block;
    margin: 1em auto;
    text-align: center;
}
div.gallery {
    clear: both;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 1em 0;
    width: 100%;
}
p.wp-caption-text {
    font-style: italic;
}
div.gallery dl {
    margin: 1em auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
div.gallery dl.gallery-columns-1 {
    width: 100%;
}
div.gallery dl.gallery-columns-2 {
    width: 49%;
}
div.gallery dl.gallery-columns-3 {
    width: 33%;
}
div.gallery dl.gallery-columns-4 {
    width: 24%;
}
div.gallery dl.gallery-columns-5 {
    width: 19%;
}
div#nav-above {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
div#nav-below {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
div#nav-images {
    height: 150px;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
div.navigation {
    height: 1.25em;
}
div.navigation div.nav-next {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
div.sidebar h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
div.sidebar input#s {
    width: 7em;
}
div.sidebar li {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 0 2em;
}
div.sidebar li form {
    margin: 0.2em 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div.sidebar ul ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 1em;
}
div.sidebar ul ul li {
    list-style: disc outside none;
    margin: 0;
}
div.sidebar ul ul ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
}
div.sidebar ul ul ul li {
    list-style: circle outside none;
}
div#menu ul li, div.gallery dl, div.navigation div.nav-previous {
    float: left;
}
div#header, div#footer {
    text-align: center;
}
input#author, input#email, input#url, div.navigation div {
    width: 50%;
}
div.gallery *, div.sidebar div, div.sidebar h3, div.sidebar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

### CSS (my own)

```
#menu {
    background-color: #F6F2E4;
}
.current_page_item {
    background-color: #EFE6CA;
}
.current_page_ancestor {
    background-color: #EFE6CA;
}
.current_page_ancestor .current_page_item {
    background-color: #EADEB8;
}
.children {
    background-color: #F6F2E4;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    width: 980px;
}
#menu ul.children a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.1em 0.2em;
}
.current_page_ancestor .children {
    background-color: #EFE6CA;
}
div#menu ul li.current_page_parent ul {
    left: 138px;
}
```

Comment: can you show us your html code and current relevant css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using something like this: http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center2.html

> This box is horizontally centered using a technique proposed to me by
>   Simon Coggins. First, the box's left edge is positioned at the
>   horizontal center of the page using "position:absolute; left:50%;".
>   Then, the box's left margin is set to the opposite of half the box's
>   width using "margin-left:-266px;".

```
body {margin:0px; padding:0px;}

#Content {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    width:500px;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:-266px;
    padding:15px;
    border:1px dashed #333;
    background-color:#eee;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to:

```
div#menu ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
div#menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

And remove:

```
div#menu ul li.current_page_parent ul {
    left: 138px;
}
```

Comment: does not work for me, as I have centered the whole page container, so that aligns with the left of the browser window, not the left of my centered container.

Comment: @BillyMoon then add `position: relative` to the `#menu` `div`